# Calculate power with large number in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate for example 257^150 but matlab shows until 257^126. I want to find the exponent "x"  in order to compute the modulus. For example the power which gives (257^x mod 1009) = 369. Thanks.

Comment: Doing your calculation at `257^126` is wrong as well. At `257^126` your floating point precision is above `10^287`, you require less than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the problem and how you would solve it. You know hat `mod(x,42)` is `23`. What is the remainder of `7*x`? Its `mod(7*42,23)`

Put into code:

```
a=257;
m=1009;
s=369;
r=1;
x=0;
while(not(r==s))
    x=x+1;
    r=mod(r*a,m);
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I would like to ask something more. Why the pow function "^"  it can't calculate numbers with big exponent?

Comment: The double precision floating point format only allows numbers within a certain range. This is the default format in matlab. Additionally, there is a precisions loss. Check `eps` `realmax` and `realmin` in the documentation and the wikipedia article about floating point for the basics. For more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @2-Chri: If you really want the number you'll need to use symbolic or variable precision math: `sym(257)^126` or `vpa(257)^126`.